# Use getattr on function

Tags: python, python-3.x, getattr

How can I use `getattr` on a function?
This is how I use it normally:

```py
df = candlestick.inverted_hammer(df, target='result')
```

But how can I do this on `getattr`?
I did as follow but it does not work:

```py
candle_names = [
    'inverted_hammer',
    'hammer',
    'hanging_man',
    .
    .
    .
]

for candle in candle_names:
    df = getattr(candlestick, candle)(df, target='result')
```

I want to pass the dataframe and the result to the `candlestick` function.

Comment: What is `candlestick`? An instance?

Comment: @Axe319 it's a sample code from github: https://github.com/SpiralDevelopment/candlestick-patterns

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:
import talib as ta

```
# extract OHLC 
df = yf.download(tickers='PETR4.SA', interval='1d', period='5y')

op = df['Open']
hi = df['High']
lo = df['Low']
cl = df['Close']
# # create columns for each pattern
candle_names = ta.get_function_groups()['Pattern Recognition']
for candle in candle_names:
# below is same as;
    df[candle] = getattr(ta, candle)(op, hi, lo, cl)
display(df)
```

This code will get all patterns of candlestick in your dataset.